# The package Microsoft.CSharp with version 4.0.0 could not be found - UWP build failed

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to **create Package App in VS2017** but I am getting this error:

```
The package Microsoft.CSharp with version 4.0.0 could not be found in C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback\. Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.   Origami
```

I google and found that run nuget command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CSharp -Version 4.0.0
```

I successfully run this command in nuget's console and here is the output:

```
    PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CSharp -Version 4.0.0
      GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.csharp/index.json
      OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.csharp/index.json 1403ms
    Restoring packages for D:\HoloLense\HoloLense Projects\HolographicAcademy-Holograms-101\Origami\App\Origami\project.json...
    Committing restore...
    Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\HoloLense\HoloLense 
Projects\HolographicAcademy-Holograms-101\Origami\App\Origami\project.lock.json
    Restore completed in 546.94 ms for D:\HoloLense\HoloLense Projects\HolographicAcademy-Holograms-101\Origami\App\Origami\Origami.csproj.
    Executing nuget actions took 978.18 ms
    Time Elapsed: 00:00:06.6826674
```

But when i try to build it again, i am getting the same error. What I am missing?

Comment: I would suggest clearing the NuGet cache (via Tools -> Nuget -> Settings -> Clear Nuget caches) and also doing a Clean and Rebuild of the solution. If it does not help, please also try closing Visual Studio and deleting all "bin" and "obj" folders in the solution

Comment: @MartinZikmund, it work with my issue! Thank you! Make it as answer,please